# make head loaded script available to AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

content called by AJAX

content requires different shapes and sizes of cluetips (I use plugin), 
so I have them in one file, which is called in head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery.clues.js">
```

sample cluetip launcher from jquery.clues.js:

```
    $('.clue550K3').cluetip({
    splitTitle: '|', 
    showTitle: false, 
    positionBy:'mouse'
    });
```

There are many like this in jquery.clues.js.

PROBLEM:

File: jquery.clues.js is not available to jQuery fetched content.

Way I make it work:

I call jquery.clues.js on each AJAX fetched page (content), but since file is called in body it is being fetched multiple times (if I have e.g. multiple AJAX fetched contents on same page).

File is exactly same.

```
https://hmvc/resources/js/jquery.clues.js?=1339917292974
https://hmvc/resources/js/jquery.clues.js?=1339917294563
https://hmvc/resources/js/jquery.clues.js?=1339917243432
etc.
```

QUESTION:

I need to either

- make AJAX content to read head delivered jquery.clues.js
- force browser to stop fetching file once it is fetched once

Is there a way to do this?

SEE THIS EXAMPLE: http://readydata.org.uk/stackstuff/

Comment: Your question isn't making sense to me.  Once you've loaded some JS, it is available anywhere in your document (as long as it's the same frame).  It doesn't matter that you are dynamically loading scripts - the clues.js plug-in will be available to any other scripts you run in that frame.

Comment: give me a moment - I'll throw together some example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your jquery.clues.js with a function:

```
window.updateClues = function () {
    $('.clue550K3').cluetip({
        splitTitle: '|',
        showTitle: false,
        positionBy:'mouse'
    });
};
updateClues();
```

Then on AJAX success call `updateClues()`. It will download only once, and execute after each request and onload.